# how to remove extra spaces accidentally typed at the end in a text box in php

Tags: php, html, removing-whitespace

This is my php code of text area and it does not remove any extra space at the end typed accidentally. Please help how to remove the extra space at the end of the text typed in the text box

```
echo"<textarea class='form-control' rows='20' cols='60' id='write".$i."'placeholder='Write Here...' style='font-family: Courier New;font-size: 15px;border:none; border-bottom:2px solid black;height:400px;'></textarea>";
```

Comment: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.trim.php

Answer (score 1):

You can use the trim function:

```
$string = trim($string);
```

https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.trim.php